# NodeJS - use of MySql query placeholder results in 1064 ER_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I'm using **Node** with the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package.

First I establish a connection:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    collation: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
});

connection.connect();
```

Then I try to insert a row to the logs table using a query placeholder:

```js
var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO logs SET ?", {ip: "127.0.0.1", request: "TEST"}, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
  });
```

Exactly as stated in the documentation:

```js
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // Neat!
});
```

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

Altough the resulting query looks correct:

```sql
INSERT INTO logs SET `ip` = '127.0.0.1', `request` = 'TEST'
```

I recieve the following error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO logs SET `ip` = '127.0.0.1', `request` = 'TEST'' at line 1
qi-node       |     at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
qi-node       |     at Query.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
qi-node       |     at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
qi-node       |     at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
qi-node       |     at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
qi-node       |     at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
qi-node       |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
qi-node       |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
qi-node       |     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
qi-node       |     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
qi-node       |     --------------------
qi-node       |     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
qi-node       |     at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
qi-node       |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/database.js:14:24)
qi-node       |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
qi-node       |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
qi-node       |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
qi-node       |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
qi-node       |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
qi-node       |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
qi-node       |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:4:16)
```

However when I execute the exact same query without the dynamic placeholder, the query works as expected and inserts the row successfully.

```js
var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO logs SET `ip` = '127.0.0.1', `request` = 'TEST'", (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
  });
```

I tried changing the db collation and also made sure that the **NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES** mode is disabled. Just for reference: The whole setup is running inside docker containers.

I can't think of any reason why this does not work. What could the error possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. It was not related to MySql or NodeJs. Instead a **bad space character** had somehow slipped into the statement, causing it to fail for no obvious reason. Which I then continued copying.

In case you are interested you can read this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space